# Cowplot failed to align legends to the left side

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I get two legends using the function `get_legend()` and align them vertically. By default, they are aligned to the center. I fail to align them to the left side using the `align="v",axis="l"`options in the function `plot_grid()` (fig. B). A reproducible example is shown below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
p1 <- ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(color=Petal.Length))+
  scale_color_viridis_c(name="")+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))

leg1 <- get_legend(p1)

p2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=Species))+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"))
leg2 <- get_legend(p2)

legs_1 <- plot_grid(leg1,leg2,ncol = 1)
legs_2 <- plot_grid(leg1,leg2,ncol = 1,align = "v",axis = "l")
legs_3 <- plot_grid(plot_grid(leg1,NULL,ncol = 2),leg2,ncol = 1)

plot_grid(legs_1,legs_2,legs_3,ncol = 3,labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

At this moment, I have to add a blank plot at the right side of the upper legend (fig. C) and adjust the width of the whole legends column. Is there any way to achive it elegantly?

Comment: Have you tried using `align="v"` **without** setting `axis="l"`?